# Specify class namespace in XAML without declaring namespace

Tags: xaml, namespaces

If I have a UserControl: `Foo.Bar.MyClass`, I know I can reference it in XAML by declaring:

```
xmlns:foobar="clr-namespace:Foo.Bar"
```

and then using the reference

```
<foobar:MyClass />
```

**But** if I declare only the Foo namespace:

```
xmlns:foo="clr-namespace:Foo"
```

is there a way for me to reference `MyClass` as `Foo:Bar.MyClass` in my XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge this is not possible.

You must add assembly reference for the type is being used in XAML.

Similarly it is not possible with C#. You are not able to access type which assembly reference is not included in using list.

Comment: But, as per the example, I am in fact declaring the assembly reference: `foo`. The trick is that I want to index into that namespace, rather than declaring every level I want access to.

Comment: In C# you need to reference the assembly, but you don't need to have it in `using` list. You can just use full type name like `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(...)`. Would be very helpful to have similar thing for XAML.